# How to create a zip with multiple pdfs using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to create all my students result as pdf, So i am using TCPDF for creating PDF. Here is my code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = "/tmp/reports.zip";
    $zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($users_list as $i => $value) {
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'pt',  'PDF_PAGE_FORMAT' , true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $obj_pdf->SetPrintHeader( false );
        $obj_pdf->SetPrintFooter( false );
        $obj_pdf->AddPage('P' , 'A4');
        $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);

        $obj_pdf->SetTopMargin($margin_top . 'px'); 
        $obj_pdf->SetLeftMargin (62);
        $obj_pdf->SetRightMargin(50); 
        $obj_pdf->SetFontSize('22px', true);
        $content = "<span style='letter-specing: 3px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 1.3;'>The Report</span>";
        $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false , true, false, "L");
        $obj_pdf->lastPage();
        $obj_pdf->Output('/tmp/report_' . $i . '.pdf', 'F');
        $obj_pdf->Close();
        $zip->addFile('/tmp/report_' . $i . '.pdf','report_' . $user->display_name . '.pdf');
}
$zip->close();

    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="certificates.zip"');
    readfile($filename);
```

The code works fine, it create a single pdf for each user with username but inside that pdf i only get last users data. I do not know why it behaving like that !! How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What is $content in writeHTML

Comment: I put the html code inside the $content variable. and use that in writeHtml()

Comment: Do not know why but i fix it myself. what i found is tcpdf is not creating more than 1 pdf in a single loop, so what i did i create a complex algorithm to make the 2 dimensional loop as 1 single dimensional loop, and it works fine.